# array of strings with string interpolation

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, string-interpolation

i have an array of strings like below

```
const array = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];
const total = 10000;
```

and i have a url that has string interpolation like below

```
const url = `http://localhost:8080/total=${total}&array=${array}`
```

which gives me back the below

```
http://localhost:8080/total=10000&array=[string1, string2, string3]
```

How can i make the array of strings to work with the string interpolation with JS.

expected result should be something like

```
http://localhost:8080/total=10000&array=["string1", "string2", "string3"]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why do you want `["string1", "string2", "string3"]` in your URL? This is a very uncommon kind of value to have in a URL.

Comment: Yeah, typically when you're sending JSON objects/data to a server you're going to POST it. If you're insistent on using GET, you'd use URL parameters (like separate parameters for each string), where they can then be parsed server-side back into an array.

Comment: That is how the backend url is constructed and we don't have control on that

Comment: Yuck. In that case, `JSON.stringify` is the way to go, as Ori Drori said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the array to a string using `JSON.stringify()`:

```js
const array = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];
const total = 10000;

const url = `http://localhost:8080/total=${total}&array=${JSON.stringify(array)}`

console.log(url)
```

As [noted by @avejidah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59203156/array-of-strings-with-string-interpolation/59203200?noredirect=1#comment104624425_59203200) you might need to use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to escape strings with reserved characters. Non reserved characters are `A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`:

```js
const array = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];
const total = 10000;

const url = `http://localhost:8080/total=${total}&array=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(array))}`

console.log(url)
```

Comment: You probably want to `encodeURIComponent`, too, because the strings might have reserved characters (dots/slashes/plus/etc.).